# How to find domain of complicated composite functions

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, function-and-relation-composition

If I was asked to find the domain of arccos($e^x$), are there universal steps I can take to be able to find the domain? I know that you want the inner function in f(g(x)) to be defined as well as the function whole but I'm not sure how to think this one through...

Comment: Are you asking about the domain of the specific function $\arccos(\mathrm{e}^x)$?  or are you asking, more generally, about how to determine the domain of composite functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$e^x$ is defined everywhere, but for $\arccos(t)$ you want $-1 \le t \le 1$.  Now $e^x > 0 > -1$, but what do you need to get $e^x \le 1$?

Answer (score 1):

For $f(g(x))$ to make sense, one needs $g(x)\in\mathrm{dom}(f)$, so $\mathrm{dom}(f\circ g) = g^{-1}(\mathrm{dom}(f))$.
With $f=\arccos$ and $g=\exp$, you have $\mathrm{dom}(f)=[-1,1]$ and $\mathrm{dom}(f\circ g)=g^{-1}([-1,1])=(-\infty,0]$.